# how to insert image in table cell in org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, libreoffice

I am trying to make a table with images and texts, then export to an odt file. How to mix text and image in org table?

Comment: Did you try just putting an image link in the table?

Comment: Yes, it works. Still need to figure out the size and alignment for each cell.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
| <c>                       |
| text                      |
| [[file:~/images/img.png]] |
```

Comment: But how to change the image size?

Comment: I don't think that's possible for images within tables...

Comment: breaks latex export for me :/

Comment: change image size by resizing it, e.g. with ImageMagick: `convert image.png -resize 32x32`

Answer (score 0):

Does the image below capture what you have in mind?

[image: Subfigure in ODT export using a list-table]

If yes, ...

1. You need `list table`-s. See `#+ATTR_ODT: :list-table t` below
2. You need to tell the exporter that what *appears* as a table, is in
   fact *a composite figure that is composed of two sub-figures*. See
   `#+ATTR_ODT: :category "figure"` below.
3. To satisfy yourself that you are indeed getting a figure, and not a
   table you can create a `TOC` for figures, and see if the composite
   image crops up in there.  See `#+toc: figures`

Here is one possible solution.

Remember, the snippet has *trailing whitespaces*.  Without them, the
lists wouldn't become lists.

```
#+toc: figures

#+CAPTION: My favourite pets
#+ATTR_ODT: :category "figure"
#+ATTR_ODT: :list-table t
- 
  -
    
    #+ATTR_ODT: :width 7
    #+CAPTION: A Dog
    [[./org-mode-unicorn.png]]

  -
    #+ATTR_ODT: :width 7
    #+CAPTION: A Cat
    [[./org-mode-unicorn.png]]
```

For this snippet to work, you need to install the [The enhanced ODT
exporter](https://kjambunathan.gitlab.io/org-mode-ox-odt/Getting-Started-with-ODT-export.html#Installation)
with `M-x package-install`.

To learn more about `list table`-s, see [Create tables with
paragraph-like content in Org mode, with the least amount of hassle –
Emacs
Notes](https://emacsnotes.wordpress.com/2020/04/26/create-tables-with-paragraph-like-content-in-org-mode-with-the-least-amount-of-hassle/)

or

[List Tables in ODT export (OpenDocument Text Exporter for Emacs’ Org
Mode)](https://kjambunathan.gitlab.io/org-mode-ox-odt/List-Tables-in-ODT-export.html#List-Tables-in-ODT-export)

Unfortunately, the ODT exporter doesn't expand the table of figures.
So, you need to do it manually.  That is, after the ODT document is
created, open it the `ODT` file in `LibreOffice` and do
`Tools`->`Update`->`Update All`.  If you do this, you will get ...

[image: Earlier sub-figure, with TOC entry]